# Delete a file inside a folder on Common Metatrader Folder with MQL4

Tags: file, mql4, mt4

I have an EA that accesses a file inside a folder called "MyFolder" in `FILE_COMMON` folder (\Terminal\Common\Files) and extracts information from it.

Then I simply want to delete that file.

I tried this and many other combinations without success:

```
FileDelete("\\MyFolder\\",FILE_COMMON + "FileToDelete.txt");
```

In sum, I want to delete this file: "...\Terminal\Common\Files\MyFolder\FileToDelete.txt"

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: try FileDelete("\\MyFolder\\" + "FileToDelete.txt",FILE_COMMON );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You need to place your files in Common\Files\ not directly in Common.
>
> If common_flag = FILE_COMMON, then the function removes the file from the shared folder for all client terminals \Terminal\Common\Files.

I am back (I am using a timer and the market was closed so I could not test it during the weekend).

Finally.... I guess I got confused when I read the "Common" bit... I assumed it was the "Common" folder and not "Common\Files".

Thank you for pointing this out. I knew this could not be that difficult!

It's now fixed and working.